# How to create a Dropdown button in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does anyone know the name of the property in which it look alike button
but once if we keep the mouse pointer 
on it then it will show like dropdown 
list options.
I want to use that in my asp.net 
project.

Comment: using jquery you can do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of the box control as such. It is an effect achieved either using javascript or CSS

Take a look at this example
http://demos.9lessons.info/DropMenu/MyDemo.html

You should also search for jquery plugins for this. Though you will get readymade code for it but it will surely not be a server side control. You have choice of either creating a user control or just use it as it is.

Comment: thanks dude :) it was very much useful :) i felt comfortable with CSS and have to work with JScript... Thanks a lot :)

Comment: hie...i felt happy with that...but still the requirement is not done...i feel more happy if i get the proper syntax for the dropdown in button control(dropdown list should come without clicking the button,i mean just by placing the mouse cursor on it)...anyways thanks a lot for the link u have provided :)

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there is no such control out of the box in asp.net. you might want to look at third party controls or do some css magic.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that maybe a standart one(1) .But I can recommend you to use telerik  if you are using it already here is a example (2)

[Example2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Example2](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ribbonbar/examples/items/defaultcs.aspx)

Comment: is it we need ajax to invoke telerik?...btw,i saw the links you have given.its very useful.i have to implement that. thanks dude :)

Comment: you need to buy telerik but believe me its ever cent worth i have work with it and its  awesome ,perfect controls with examples and god support !! np (if you want mark my answer as useful ;))